How can I append a paragraph to a document with some bold and some regular text using google apps script?
I'm using google app script to automate the process of transforming responses collected from a google form into a google document with some formatting . The script I have iterates over the spreadsheet rows, treating each cell differently based on its index. Here's a visual of a spreadsheet and the resulting text I want to create inside of google doc:
spreadsheet 'responses'
|         | What's your favorite animal? | when did you graduate? | Will you come to the party?|
| Janice  | dogs                         | 1992                   | yes                        |
| Soyoung | I like frogs                 | 2003                   | I'll be there              |
| Cary    | not sure!                    |   x                    | I can't come :(            |

inside of document 'formatted responses':
Janice
What's your favorite animal?: dogs
when did you graduate?: 1992
Will you come to the party?: yes
Soyoung
What's your favorite animal?: dogs
when did you graduate?: 2003
Will you come to the party?: I'll be there
Cary
What's your favorite animal?: not sure!
when did you graduate?:
Will you come to the party?: I can't come :(
Currently the script can do everything except bold the questions. I just can't figure out how to only bold just the questions.
I found the setBold() function on the documentation, but it seems like I can only use it with a Text object, and I can't figure out to work it into the way I've implemented my script already. I'm using appendParagraph() to build the lines of content inside my document because things need to be in order and on the same line...
I found this post and I tried to work in what they did but still using appendParagraph() but it didn't work. This is the basic format I'm following for adding text into my document, I'd appreciate any suggestions.
// for each user, the header is the question and the cell holds the user's response to that question
var header = headers[cellIndex];
body.appendParagraph(header + " " + cell.toString());


Hey! If the structure is always the same, why not creating a template with your questions in blod and some tags for the answers? What's your favorite animal?: {{What's your favorite animal?}}, so then whith the function body.replaceText() you can easily inject your data without worrying about the formatting

@Lidia oh I don't know what a template is, maybe that's why. I don't know how many responses there will be, would it still work? If you can link some documentation or an example I can take a look and try it.

Of course! You can have code sample and explanation here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/120138245/auto-fill-google-docs-from-google-sheets-using-google-apps-script?hl=en
Basically you prepare a Google Docs with the format that you want and with tags where you want to put data, then the script loops through the sheet and creates a copy of the doc for each row, replacing the tags with the data from the sheets!

As @Lidia suggested an approach is to use an additional document as a template which stores the text formatting. Then append that template's paragraphs while replacing placeholders with form responses.
Note that the script wipes the target document each time (constant document each time, the script) before copying over all the form's results. I'll likely update that.
Script
/**
 *   +---------------------------------------------+
 *   |  Form Results to Doc Using Doc as Template  | 
 *   +---------------------------------------------+ 
 * 
 *   2024-05-12
 * 
 *   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78451410/  
 *   How can I append a paragraph to a document with some bold and 
 *   some regular text using google apps script?
 * 
 */

const sheetId = "xyz123";
const templateId = "abc678";
const documentId = "lmn789";
const setTimeZone = "EST"
const dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy   h:mm a";

function formResultsToDocUsingTemplate () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const template = DocumentApp.openById(templateId);
  const document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  const body = document.getBody();
  const templateBody = template.getBody(); 
  const paragraphs = templateBody.getParagraphs();
  const range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),setTimeZone,dateFormat);
  
  body.clear() && body.insertParagraph(0, date) && body.insertHorizontalRule(1); 
  range.getValues().forEach(function(r, i) {  
    i && r.forEach(function (c, j) { 
      let txt = paragraphs[j].copy().replaceText("%"+(j+1)+"%",c);
        (j == 3) && txt.appendText('\n');
        body.appendParagraph(txt);
    });
  });
}


Sample Template
%1%
What's your favorite animal?: %2%
when did you graduate?: %3%
Will you come to the party?: %4%



Sample Sheet


Sample Document (Results)



